# Getting worse results on gcloud vs local training

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to understand why my local results are better than the gcloud results.

In local, I run a job like this:

```
gcloud ml-engine local train --module-name trainer.task --package-path trainer -- --vocabulary-file trainer/data/vocab.txt --class-files $CLASS_FILES --job-dir trainer/lr0001 --num-epochs 5000 --learning-rate 0.0001 --train-batch-size 4 --eval-batch-size 64 --export-format CSV
```

And for gcloud I run

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOBNAME --job-dir gs://.../lr0001 --module-name trainer.task --package-path trainer --region us-west1 --runtime-version 1.10 -- --vocabulary-file gs://.../vocab.txt --class-files $GS_CLASS_FILES --num-epochs 5000 --learning-rate 0.0001 --train-batch-size 4 --eval-batch-size 64 --export-format CSV
```

I've fixed the seed, ran it multiple times, checked python 2 vs python 3, but the gcloud results are still worse than my local run.

One last bit of clue that I've found is that local logs look like this:

```
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.63639945, step = 401 (0.170 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 485.821
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.61793035, step = 501 (0.206 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 490.795
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.5869169, step = 601 (0.204 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 619.825
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.5738391, step = 701 (0.161 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 605.698
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.51589084, step = 801 (0.165 sec)
```

whereas gcloud logs look like they are doubling up or something

```
I  master-replica-0 loss = 0.40115586, step = 2202 (0.367 sec) master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 global_step/sec: 555.434 master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 global_step/sec: 498.601 master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 loss = 0.4367655, step = 2402 (0.470 sec) master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 global_step/sec: 366.906 master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 global_step/sec: 408.556 master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 loss = 0.41198668, step = 2602 (0.492 sec) master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 global_step/sec: 388.73 master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 global_step/sec: 380.982 master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 loss = 0.35386887, step = 2802 (0.522 sec) master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 global_step/sec: 401.002 master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 global_step/sec: 465.647 master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 loss = 0.4420835, step = 3002 (0.417 sec) master-replica-0
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

The only thing I've found in the internet so far are these SO questions with no answer:

[Results of training a Keras model different on Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047041/results-of-training-a-keras-model-different-on-google-cloud)

[Differents outputs from predictions using Tensorflow from same data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462765/differents-outputs-from-predictions-using-tensorflow-from-same-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I believe it's due to some buggy interaction between Keras and the Estimator API in tensorflow 1.10 (current gcloud version), but not in >=1.11 (what I was using locally).

I filed a bug report here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24299

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs what I guess is happening is that the gcloud on cloud is picking up the checkpoint and resuming the training (See number of steps). Can you do the following test: Run local from scratch and make sure no output model folders exist and then repeat same setup on cloud and compare.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the problem. I just randomly picked a few lines from both local and cloud logs. I wanted to show that the cloud logs had 2x the number of `global_step/sec` lines per `loss` line, suggesting that something weird (something running twice?) is happening in cloud.